# DOM XML losing data on loadXML

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need help with PHP DOM XML.

I have this code:

```
$xmlresponse= file_get_contents("https://webservices.cebroker.com/cebrokerwebservice.asmx/UploadXMLString?InXML=$data");
print_r ($xmlresponse);
echo "<br /> <br />";
$xmlFile = new DOMDocument();
$works = $xmlFile->loadXML($xmlresponse);
echo "working = " . $works;
$searchNode = $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName( "licensee" );
print_r ($xmlFile);
```

This is the response. The first XML is the response from the web service. The sencond XML file is the one I get after I try to load the first XML reponse into a new XML object.

```
<licensees>
   <licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="11/16/2013 8:59:16 PM" />
   <licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="PN" licensee_number="1063421" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="11/16/2013 8:59:16 PM" />
</licensees>

working = 1

DOMDocument Object ( [doctype] => [implementation] => (object value omitted) [documentElement] => (object value omitted) [actualEncoding] => utf-8 [encoding] => utf-8 [xmlEncoding] => utf-8 [standalone] => 1 [xmlStandalone] => 1 [version] => 1.0 [xmlVersion] => 1.0 [strictErrorChecking] => 1 [documentURI] => /home/content/14/6722114/html/CCRN411/inc/ [config] => [formatOutput] => [validateOnParse] => [resolveExternals] => [preserveWhiteSpace] => 1 [recover] => [substituteEntities] => [nodeName] => #document [nodeValue] => [nodeType] => 9 [parentNode] => [childNodes] => (object value omitted) [firstChild] => (object value omitted) [lastChild] => (object value omitted) [previousSibling] => [attributes] => [ownerDocument] => [namespaceURI] => [prefix] => [localName] => [baseURI] => /home/content/14/6722114/html/CCRN411/inc/ [textContent] => )
```

Why is my data disappearing when I try to loadXML to be able to parse?

Comment: BTW, when I copy and paste the xmlresponse information into a string in the php file, the results are perfect. So, my question is, why does the loadXML not convert the xmlresponse to a valid XML object, but if I use the info as a literal string and try to loadXML it, it works fine?

Comment: More info. if I add the following to my php file - `code`$xmlFile = new DOMDocument;
$works = $xmlFile->loadXML($xmlresponse);
$filename3 = "testing123responseDOM.xml";
$xmlFile->save($filename3) or die("Error"); `code`    It saves a file with the following `code` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns=".../CEBrokerWebService/">&lt;licensees&gt;&lt;`code` Why did I lose the < and > brackets in the actual XML?

Comment: Hi Henry, please add the info by editing your question, much easier to read in contrast to adding as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. Not sure if it is the best solution or just a hack, but I got the API response and applied html_decode_entities to it and regexed out the xmlns name space info. Then I wrote it to a file. I created a new DOM document and immediately reloaded it from the saved xml file. Then it all worked. If this is a hack and there is a cleaner way to accomplish the task, would someone please post it and let me know.

Comment: The example XML provided in the question doesn't have any xmlns namespace attributes - if you provide the full XML it will be easier to help.

Comment: @AlfEaton - It did not display when I printed it out so I did not realize it was there. I have read other postings on similar situation and found that they also report having to save xml file and reload to make it work. Not sure why it assigns a namespace, but it also turned < and > into $&lt and $&gt

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getElementsByTagNameNS`, as the element is namespaced:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://example.com/CEBrokerWebService/">
    <licensees>
       <licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="11/16/2013 8:59:16 PM" />
       <licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="PN" licensee_number="1063421" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="11/16/2013 8:59:16 PM" />
    </licensees>
</string>
END;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.com/CEBrokerWebService/', 'licensee');
printf("Found %d nodes\n", $nodes->length);

print $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: When the XML is returned, it, for some reason removes the beginning angle brackets rendering the resulting string not valid XML.

Comment: The code above works perfectly here - maybe post the actual code that you're using, as well as the actual input XML and output XML that you're seeing?